# How to use template variable outside a loop?

Tags: go, go-templates

In a go template, I'd like to get the last message in a loop, to be used outside the loop:

```
    {{range $m := .messages}}      
            <div>Message subject: {{$m.Subject}}</div>

            {{$lastMsg := $m}}
    {{end}}


    <div>The last message's subject: {{$lasMsg.Subject}}</div>
```

But this does not work and I get this error:

```
 undefined variable "$lastMsg"
```

I have also tried `{{.lastMsg := $m}}` but then I get:

```
 unexpected ":=" in operand
```

So how can I fix this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to declare the lastMsg variable outside the range loop in order to use it outside the loop

```
{{$lastMsg := ""}} // declare outside the loop
{{range $m := .messages}}      
        <div>Message subject: {{$m.Subject}}</div>

        {{$lastMsg = $m}} // assign the value 
{{end}}
```